# Python compare 2 lists by index

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

How can one iterate through two lists an compare values by index. Ive tried both for loop and the use of zip.

```
 for a,b in zip(list1,list2):
    if a[0] in b[4]
       print ('found')
```

EDIT

This is what Im after

```
  results = cHandlers.fetchall() #from an sql query
  response = (r.json()) # from a json request
  for u in range(0,3):
     for row in results:
        if (response['data'][u]['item']) == row[3]
           print (found)
```

Comment: It's not obvious to me what exactly you're wanting to compare. Can you give an example with some data and show exactly which items from the example dataset you expect to be compared?

Comment: Added some extra info as you will be able see thanks

Comment: OK, I sort of understand what you want to do. But what's wrong with the code you've shown? Are you getting an error? If so, give the full traceback. Are you getting wrong results? If so, give an example of the data, and show the output you're getting and what you want instead. In other words, you need to include a [mcve]. Also, you've tagged your question with both the Python 2 and Python 3 tags. Usually you only want one of those (or neither if the version doesn't matter), and you should always include the plain python tag as well.

Comment: Sorry my bad your right it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` generates a list of tuples `(a,b)` with `a` being elements from `list1` and `b` from `list2`. To check all the elements you can do the following

```
list1 = [1,2,3,5,4]
list2 = [5,3,4,3,4]

for a in zip(list1,list2):
    if a[0] == a[1]:
        print ('found')
```

To check specific indices you can use this:

```
zipped = zip(list1,list2)
if zipped[0][0] == zipped[4][1]:
    print ('found')
```

Again, in `zipped` tuple element 0 corresponds to `list1` and element 1 to `list2`.